# Dynamic columns width of ListView in List mode like Explorer in Windows 7

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

When you chose "List" mode in Windows 7 Explorer it will show list of items with columns of different width, this is what I am talking about:

[image: Windows 7 Explorer]

Can anybody tell please how I can achieve same with ListView in .NET 4?

When I try "ListView.View = List" it makes all columns same size as the longest item in any of columns which looks weird in case if all elements are short but only few ones are long.

Answer (score 0):

set the column width of listview either to -1 or -2, -1 for autosizing the column to the longest items in the column and -2 for autosizing the column to the lenght of column header

Comment: Thank you for answering Mahdi! I know about Magic Numbers -1 and -2 but as far as I know it's for the Details mode only. So it seems like it's not the solution here or I simply couldn't understand you completely. Can you just post a code example to reproduce ListView of Windows 7 Explorer with different columns width like on the picture above?